# How do I make "if statement" work properly with on button_click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, gridview

I am having trouble getting the if statement to work in my program. The program allows the reordering of a Gridview. After the reordering of the Gridview, I have successfully managed to grab the new ordered values. However, before I save the new order to by database I must compare the values in the programs Columns to make sure that programs are in order from least to greatest. if they are not, then I need to make my pop/alert box via "ModalPopupExtender1.Show();". When I debug the program to see what value are being compared in the "If-Statement" I find that the values for comparison (integers) are correct, but when the comparison is true that a program is out of proper order, it doesn't fire off for some reason.

here is the code for the section I am referencing:

**ASPX CODE: **

```
protected void SaveReorder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        String fix;
        String fix2;

        int comp1;
        int comp2;

        // stores id_ in array
        string[] idNatColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("Natural");
        string[] progIDColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("Program");
        string[] RecNoIDColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("RecNo");
        string[] idSortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("SortOrder");


         List<String> listStrLineElements;
         List<String> listStrLineElements2;


       for (int j = 0; j < progIDColumn.Length - 1; j++ )
        {


           fix = progIDColumn[j].ToString();
           fix2 = progIDColumn[j + 1].ToString();


            listStrLineElements = fix.Split(' ').ToList();
            listStrLineElements2 = fix2.Split(' ').ToList();


           comp1  = Convert.ToInt32(listStrLineElements[1]);
           comp2 = Convert.ToInt32(listStrLineElements2[1]);

                if( comp1 > comp2 )
                {
                    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                   //Proceed to update the new order in the database

                }


       }


}
```

Comment: Check [ModalPopupExtender Show() not firing ASP.NET C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/831566/ModalPopupExtender-Show-not-firing-ASP-NET-Csharp) if it solves your issue. You might also want to add a `break;` after showing the modal pop-up to stop the loop iteration.

Comment: Do note that this is server-side code. The (client-side) popup can only show *after* this method completes

Comment: Thank you both for the input. I am using ToolScriptManager. Is there a way to make it work? with getting a popup to show